# Using loops to print the values list and data.frame in R R2HTML

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I'm using the library R2HTML to create a report of the iterations of a process. 
I have the data of interactions stored in a list, and the parameter used for each iteration on a data.frame. 
I'm using the following function, but I can not I print the iterations. 
I only print the "HTML.title" a single time, and I added a NULL between each title. You know if you can use the for loop or while within the code R2HTML? Any idea I do wrong?

```
HTML_OUTPUT_ITERATIONS<-function(epc_list, df_power_values){
  require(R2HTML)
  DIRECTOR<-getwd()
  FOLDER<-"/outputs/"
  OUTPUTS<-paste(DIRECTOR,FOLDER,sep="")
  PATH_OUTPUTS<-gsub(" ","", OUTPUTS, fixed=TRUE)
  i<-1
  HTMLStart(outdir=PATH_OUTPUTS, file="iterations",extension="html", echo=FALSE, HTMLframe=TRUE)
  HTML.title("Iterations Log Report", HR=1)
  HTML.title("Report of the data obtained from the readings that have been made during the test", HR=3)
  while(i<=length(df_power_values)){
    HTML.title("Power:")
    print(df_power_values[i,1])
    HTML.title("EPC read:")
    print(epc_list[i]
    i<-i+1
  }
  HTMLStop()
}
```

Data.frame (df_power_values) values:

```
        V1
1   31.5
2   31.0
3   30.5
4   30.0
5   29.5
6   29.0
7   28.5
8   28.0
9   27.5
10  27.0
11  26.5
12  26.0
13  25.5
14  25.0
15  24.5
16  24.0
17  23.5
18  23.0
19  22.5
20  22.0
```

List epc_list:

```
[[1]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A016
5 00000000000000000000A340
6 00000000000000000000A012
7 00000000000000000000A051
8 00000000000000000000A274

[[2]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[3]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[4]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[5]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A012
6 00000000000000000000A051
7 00000000000000000000A274

[[6]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A012
6 00000000000000000000A051
7 00000000000000000000A274

[[7]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[8]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[9]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[10]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[11]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[12]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[13]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[14]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[15]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[16]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[17]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A340
5 00000000000000000000A051
6 00000000000000000000A274

[[18]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A051
5 00000000000000000000A274

[[19]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A051
5 00000000000000000000A274

[[20]]
                       epc
1 00000000000000000000A111
2 00000000000000000000B109
3 00000000000000000000A279
4 00000000000000000000A051
5 00000000000000000000A274
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of your data frame is 1, so your loop ends after one iteration. Instead of `while(i<=length(df_power_values))`, try `while (i <= nrow(df_power_values))` or `while (i <= length(df_power_values$V1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! were right, then I saw it :) thank you very much, here I leave the code

```
while(i<=nrow(df_power_values)){
  HTML.title("Power:")
      HTML(df_power_values[i,1], digits=4)
    HTML.title("EPC read:")
      HTML(epc_list[i])

    i<-i+1
  }
  HTMLhr()
  HTMLStop()
```